# Getting the response for res.write() in nodejs using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have the following router implemented which sends the data every one second.

```
router.get('/api/test-router', function(req,res){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    setInterval(function(){
        res.write(
            currentTime.getHours() + ':' + currentTime.getMinutes() + ':' + currentTime.getSeconds() + "\n"
        );

        setTimeout(function() {
            res.end();
        }, 10000);

    },1000);
})
```

I want to get the response of the above router on my client side using the angularjs $http.get method.

```
$http.get('/api/test-router').then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data)
});
```

The above angularjs code do not print anything in the console window.

Please help me to sort this problem out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I managed to solve the problem with the XMLhttpRequest() in native javascript.

```
var url = '/api/test-router';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET", url,true);
xhr.seenBytes = 0;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(xhr.readyState > 2) {
        var newData = xhr.responseText.substr(xhr.seenBytes);
        console.log(newData);
        xhr.seenBytes = xhr.responseText.length; 
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

that server side code will probably raise an exception, you cannot send multiple response to the client (looking through your code, each second you setup a timeout that will trigger a `res.end()` after 10 seconds, that means ending the response multiple times, and since you ended the response you can't write to res anymore).

You're trying to force multiple responses from the server to the client, and you can't do this with plain XmlHTTPrequest

With the standard approach of an ajax call the server will simply respond as soon as he receive the request, it can't send data unless the client has explicitly requested it.

If you need the server to push data to the client you most likely need  a websocket connection. both sides can send data whenever they want. That's not the case for an ajax request.

take a look at [socketIo](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Yeah, the server will throw an error because after 10 seconds the respones will end. But, before it raises an error, it will send the data to the client every 1 second.  (I used the above code only for the purpose of example)